# How to create a Weighted Sum Score based on a second dataset for specific variables

Tags: r, database, dplyr, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I have to create a weighted sum score (WSum) based on several variables. For instance, `mydata` has three variables (A, B, and C). I have to create a 'WSum' score in which I multiple each of these variables by the weights present in the `weights` dataset, and sum all of them `(A*0.5 + B*1.2 + C*2)`. I have to do all of that without altering other variables in the dataset, for instance, in this case, the variable ID.

*PS: I can definitely do it manually `mutate(Wsum = (A*0.5 + B*1.2 + C*2))`. But I would like to automatize this process, because, as you might guess, I don't have only 3 variables, and that will not be a one-time job. Thanks in advance.*

## Example data

### Packages required

```
library(dplyr)
```

### Example Data

```
mydata <- tibble(ID = (01, 02
                 A = c(1, 2, 3),
                 B = c(2, 5, 4),
                 C = c(3, 6, 1))

>    # A tibble: 3 x 4
>     ID     A     B     C
>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
>1     1     1     2     3
>2     2     2     5     6
>3     3     3     4     1
```

### Data Weight Dictionary

```
weights <- tibble( variables = c("A", "B", "C"),
                   w = c(0.5, 1.2, 2))

># A tibble: 3 x 2
>  variables     w
>  <chr>     <dbl>
>1 A           0.5
>2 B           1.2
>3 C           2
```

## Expected result

```
># A tibble: 3 x 5
>     ID     A     B     C  Wsum
>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
>1     1     1     2     3   8.9
>2     2     2     5     6  19  
>3     3     3     4     1   8.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `base R`, use `%*%` or `crossprod` after converting to `matrix`

```
mydata$Wsum <- as.vector(as.matrix(mydata[weights$variables]) %*% 
       with(weights, setNames(w, variables)))
```

-output

```
mydata$Wsum
[1]  8.9 19.0  8.3
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`, loop `across` the columns in the 'mydata', get the corresponding value from `deframe`d (converted to named vector) 'weights', multiply and get the `rowSums` to create the 'Wsum' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
mydata <- mydata %>%
  mutate(Wsum = rowSums(across(all_of(weights$variables),
    ~ .x * deframe(weights)[[cur_column()]])))
mydata
# A tibble: 3 × 4
      A     B     C  Wsum
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     3   8.9
2     2     5     6  19  
3     3     4     1   8.3
```